# SharePoint Modern JSON Formatting - Can "setValue" be Used to Select a Value at First Page Load

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-web-part

I am working with SharePoint Online Modern and I am using a List View Web Part in a Site Page. At first load I need an item in the LVWP to be "selected". I've been looking for a way to do this with JSON, and have seen many examples of people using the setValue method to change values of related items after one item is selected.
My question is this - is there a way to use setValue in a JSON formatted column or view to make an item selected on first page load?
If setValue can't be used to do this is there anything that can?

Comment: setValue can be used to update the values in list columns on button/link click inside list view. It cannot be used automatically on page load. Also, you cannot use it to select item in the list view.

Comment: What can be used ??